# Electron builder wont properly install

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

Im trying to electron-build my test project

```js
{
  "name": "////////",
  "version": "1.0.21",
  "description": "///////",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/electron .",
    "build": "build --win",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w bcrypt"
  },
  "build": {
    "squirrelWindows": {
      "remoteReleases": ""
    },
    "win": {}
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^2.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^20.26.1",
    "electron-packager": "^12.1.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.1",
    "electron-reload": "^1.2.2",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^2.23.3",
    "electron-window-state": "^4.1.1",
    "electron-winstaller": "^2.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.3",
    "tedious": "^2.6.1",
    "update-electron-app": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

and for some time this works fine, i get my exe.file, blockmap file and latest.yml, however when i install the builded application i get the following error:

[squirrel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZwOL.png)

I know this issue is caused by the fact that it think the application is NOT installed, but what am i doing wrong? I dont get any error up til this point
The code for this error is the following:

```js
    <script>
      //const package = require('./package.json')
      
      const remote = require("electron").remote
      const autoUpdater = remote.autoUpdater
    
      autoUpdater.on('update-availabe', () => {
        console.log('update available')
      })
      autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
        console.log('checking-for-update')
      })
      autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', () => {
        console.log('update-not-available')
      })
    
      autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        alert("Install?")
          autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
      })
    
      autoUpdater.setFeedURL('https://x.x.x.x.x/x/')
    
      autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
      window.autoUpdater = autoUpdater
      
      </script>
```

Comment: Just a guess: maybe FeedURL is broken somehow? Can you check Network panel? Maybe there is a network error with this URL.

Comment: already tried replacing the FeedURL, and if that is the mistake the error box will be displayed an alert stating that the url isn't avaliable at the moment

Comment: Problem is something with squirrel, just not sure what

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but if the field `"name"` of your `package.json` file is really `"////////"`, it may be invalid. For instance, according to [package.json | npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

> The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line,
>   and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe
>   characters.

Comment: oh thats only to "not show" it to everyone, the regular folder has name and description :D otherwise thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late but it's because you're declaring squirrel as a developer dependency and won't be included in the production build. For anyone else having issues like this, if it says it's missing a module, just include it as a dependency.